# Call a method from superclass

Tags: tcl

I'm currently writing an IRC library in Tcl using TclOO.

Now I want to implement output queues, because most IRC Servers don't like it if you send too much text at once.

The superclass has a method `send` that just write stuff to the socket:

```
oo::class ::irc::core {
    method send {text} {
        variable socket
        puts $socket $text
    }
    # ...
}
```

To implement the queue, I decided to extend my core class and override `send`:

```
oo::class ::irc::queue {
    method send {text} {
        # For this example, we just delay it.
        after 50 [list [namespace which my] DrainQueue $text]
    }
    method DrainQueue {text} {
        # Now call [send] from ::irc::core
        my send $text
    }
}
```

This obviously doesn't work.

**TL;DR** In Java, I'd use `super.Method()`, what is the TclOO equivalent of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing at the script level to allow you to call an arbitrary method using a superclass view. It's probably better to structure your code using a coroutine so that you delay the execution of the code that way. Then you can write this:

```
method send {text} {
    after 50 [info coroutine]
    yield
    next $text
}
```

---

### Alternative

To write things without this, perhaps the easiest technique is to put the *actual* sender in a different, private, method in the superclass and forward to it from the public method. Then you can override and call however you want.

```
oo::class ::irc::core {
    method Send {text} {
        variable socket
        puts $socket $text
    }
    forward send my Send
    # ...
}

oo::class ::irc::queue {
    method send {text} {
        after 50 [list [namespace which my] DrainQueue $text]
    }
    method DrainQueue {text} {
        my Send $text
    }
}
```

---

### The Real Way (for C hackers)

The C API *can* support this sort of behaviour by adding a [method name mapper](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/Class.htm) to the object, but this isn't functionally exposed to scripts (except in [incr Tcl] 4) and it has the disadvantage of necessarily constraining the space of legal method names (which is currently largely unlimited, though I reserve some things for future extensions, such as multi-word names). I'm guessing that you wouldn't immediately think of method name mapping as a way of dealing with this sort of issue, but it's the intended use of the mechanism.

Exposing the mapper API to scripts perhaps ought to be higher on my agenda; to date, it's been a long way down (way below sub-methods and garbage collection…)

Comment: The actual code is a little bit more complex, I try to combine messages, send out 1 message/second. some other parts also expect that `send` will return immediately.

Comment: I could call `send` from `DrainQueue`, and check there if it was called from `DrainQueue`. I still don't like that.

Comment: Well, the problem is that you can't start the call at arbitrary depths; when you call a method, it _will_ start with the first item described by `info object call`.

Comment: Maybe this feature should be added.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't write your code in a way that requires it… :p

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Thinking about it (and with less grouchiness from non-working builds and interminable meetigs) there's a few better ways to do it. Updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Have you thought of using `next`?
Maybe this will help (TCL 8.6), if I understood what you've wanted, next should get the job done.
See tiny code below:
`oo::class create one  {

     method moo { } {

          puts "I am one"

     }

}

oo::class create two  {

     superclass one

     method moo { } {

          puts "I am two"

          next

     }

}

two create foo

foo moo
exit`
The output is:
`I am two
I am one`
The next calls the superclass method moo